# Type hole in where clause not working

Tags: haskell

I have the following

```
readStatement :: String -> IO  [Transaction]
readStatement path = do
   csvData <- readFile path
   return $ catMaybes (map _ (splitOn "\r" csvData))
```

The GHC find the following type for the hole `[Char] -> Maybe Transaction`.
Now, if I give a name to this hole and move into a where clause

```
readStatement :: String -> IO  [Transaction]
readStatement path = do
   csvData <- readFile path
   return $ catMaybes (map process (splitOn "\r" csvData))
   where process = _
```

GHC can't find the type of the new line but gives :

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: t
Where: ‘t’ is a rigid type variable bound by
           the inferred type of process :: t at Statement.hs:63:11
Relevant bindings include
  process :: t (bound at Statement.hs:63:11)
  path :: String (bound at Statement.hs:60:15)
  readStatement :: String -> IO [Transaction]
    (bound at Statement.hs:60:1)
In the expression: _
In an equation for ‘process’: process = _
In an equation for ‘readStatement’:
    readStatement path
      = do { csvData <- readFile path;
             return $ catMaybes (map process (splitOn "\r" csvData)) }
      where
          process = _
```

The code is strictly equivalent, so how comes the type inference doesn't give the same result ? (I'm using GHC 7.8.3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the  following code

```
let x = something
in f x
```

type inference of `x = something` does not consider `f`. That is, the type of `something` is inferred, generalized to polymorphic types, and `x` gets that type. This might assign `x` a type which is more general than the type needed by `f`.

More concretely, in

```
let x = \y->y
in  x "hello"
```

we infer the polymorphic binding `x :: forall a. a->a`.
Note that `String` does not show up, yet.

I guess GHC prints type hole information at that time, just after having performed type inference on the `let` definition. In the posted example,

```
do one
   two
where process = _
```

we infer `_ :: t` without looking at the context and print that type. If you instead want a more specialized (monomorphic) type, try instead

```
(\process -> do
   one
   two
) _
```

Above, we do not use `let` or `where`, so only monomorphic types will be inferred.

Comment: so basically, in my example, `process` is polymorphic. Am I right ?

Comment: It's not the monomorphism restriction that makes `let` and `where` capable of binding values at polymorphic types, but instead "`let` generalization": unlike for function arguments, the to-be-determined type variables in a `let` (or `where`) binding are made polymorphic instead of being instantiated. So your `x` will always be `x :: a -> a`. This is the only place where Hindley-Milner type inference will produce polymorphic types. The MR is only about type classes, and non-constrained type variables can still be generalized: `let f = \x y = (x,y*y)` produces `f :: t -> Integer -> (t,Integer)`.

Comment: (Though the story is slightly complicated in GHC: the `-XGADTs` and `-XTypeFamilies` flags turn on the `-XMonoLocalBinds` flag, which [disables `let`-generalization](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#mono-local-binds) for local bindings!  This is important for type inference reasons, apparently, but I don't understand the details.)

Comment: @AntalS-Z You are right: unconstrained type variables are indeed unaffected by the DMR. Thank you. I corrected the answer accordingly.